# [Vue warn]: Property or method "trendingMovies" is not defined on the instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Does anyone know why or what is the cause of this error?

I'm trying to send the data to another view to call into a carousel by recycling the carousel file

In my home I am calling this data but it shows me the error that I already mentioned.

```
<app-carousel v-if="trendingSeries" :title="$t('home.new_tv_series')" :view-all-url="SeriesUrl" :data="trendingSeries"></app-carousel>
<app-carousel v-if="trendingMovies" :title="$t('home.new_movies')" :view-all-url="MoviesUrl" :data="trendingMovies"></app-carousel>
```

In the export default I have this:

```
mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch("GET_HOME_LIST");
},

computed: {
  ...mapState({
    data: state => state.home.data
  }),

  MoviesUrl() {
    return { name: 'movies' };
  },

  SeriesUrl() {
    return { name: 'series' };
  },
},

async asyncData ({ error }) {
  try {
    const trendingMovies = await this.treding('movies');
    const trendingSeries = await this.treding('series');

    return { trendingMovies, trendingSeries};
  } catch {
    error({ statusCode: 504, message: 'Data not available' });
  }
},

methods: {
  async treding(media) {
    let { data } = await axios.get('/api/v1/get/type/' + media);
    return data.list;
  }
}
```

When I put in the mounted calling class treding if it prints in the console what I want.

```
mounted() {
  this.treding('movies');
},
```

[image]

What I actually receive is a string that I show later.
[image]

I would be very grateful if you could help me with this problem that I am looking for a way to fix a problem in which I started a reward but it seems that it is necessary to do it another way.

Comment: not enough info in the question ... which line of code throws the error? if it's the console.log, then what does `this.$store.dispatch("GET_TREDING_LIST", "movies");` return? What does the vuex action that is triggered by that dispatch return?

Comment: In the 2 constants it marks me as an error. What you get are string. The console log is not the one that marks error.

Comment: Nothing in the code in this question would throw that error. You only get this when you try to use a property in your template that is not defined in `data` or `computed` and your template isn't using `trendingMovies`

Comment: I'm not sure `dispatch` is what you really want to do ... it's really odd that the error is caused by `const trendingMovies`

Comment: Assuming your Vuex actions return promises, you seem to be also missing some `await` tokens

Comment: Update the question by adding more data that can help solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thats not the way to use `asyncData`

You want to grab the SEO boost for that specific page but you wont get it if you call an method that doesnt return nothing.

Also you use `async` but i do not see any `await`. Anyway try this out

```
async asyncData ({ error }) {
  try {
    const trendingMovies = await this.treding('movies');
    const trendingSeries = await this.treding('series');

    return { trendingMovies, trendingSeries};
  } catch {
    error({ statusCode: 504, message: 'Data not available' });
  }
},

methods: {
  async treding(media) {
    let { data } = await axios.get('/api/v1/get/type/' + media);
    return data.list;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, friend. I keep getting the same error, friend.

Comment: I always get the same error. I look at which side it comes out and I realize that it is in the `v-if ="trendingSeries"` of the `app-carousel`.

Comment: I always get this kind of error: [Vue warn]: Property or method "trendingMovies" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

Comment: thats what i dont understand that you get `trendingMovies` as undefined and show us `trendingSeries` are you sure the error happens on that liine?

Comment: What happens is that there are two `app-carousel`.
One passes the series and the other the movies. But they generate the same error but only the `trendingMovies` changes